# iOS/Objective-C: Get list of notifications that have fired prior to opening app (number on badge)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

Many apps such as LinkedIn have a notifications tab or button accessible from the home view with a badge showing the number of notifications. When you click on the tab, it takes you to a view controller (and tableview) with all of the notifications that have come in.

Is there a way to access local notifications after they have fired? Or once fired, do they disappear unless saved in core data or somewhere.

I am able to access pending local notifications--the ones that have not yet fired--and display them in a a tableview with the following code:

```
// Get list of local notifications and display in cellforrowatindexpath in tableview
 NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
     NSLog(@"localNotifications%@",localNotifications);
 UILocalNotification *localNotification = [localNotifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [cell.textLabel setText:localNotification.alertBody];
     [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[localNotification.fireDate description]];
```

However, I have not been able to find a way to get the notifications that have already fired while the app was closed.  In other words, if the badge shows 5 notifications meaning 5 have piled up, I have not been able to find a way to retrieve these five fired notifications.

If you need to save them, can anyone recommend a good way? Hate to get core data involved.  How would you persist the array of notifications when the app is closed.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken but I believe there is no automatic way. Since even the notification number on the icon is manually set:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:12];
```

So you need to handle it by yourself (coredata/nsuserdefaults/etc).

Comment: OK.  So how could I keep track of which ones have fired even manually? There is an array of scheduled notifications.  But once one fires, it disappears from the array and, based on my somewhat foggy understanding, this happens behind the scenes at the system level so there is no opportunity to grab it as it fires....